# "rootless" docker gets permission denied, but account running docker does not - why?

Tags: docker, daemon, systemd, rootless

I am running docker "rootless" according to this guide: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

The user which actually runs docker is `svc_test`.

When I try and start a docker container which has diretory mounts which don't exists - the docker daemon (a.k.a. `svc_test` user) attempts to `mkdir` these directories, but fails with

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/dir_path/dir_name': mkdir /dir_path/dir_name: permission denied.
```

When I (`svc_test`) them attempt to do `mkdir /dir_path/dir_name` I succeed without any issues.

What is going on here and why does this happen?
Clearly I am missing something, but I can't trace what is that exactly.

Update 1:
This is the specific docker cmd I use to run the container:

```
docker run -d --restart unless-stopped \
    --name questdb \
    -e QDB_METRICS_ENABLED=TRUE \
    --network="host" \
    -v /my_mounted_volume/questdb:/questdb \
    -v /my_mounted_volume/questdb/public:/questdb/public \
    -v /my_mounted_volume/questdb/conf:/questdb/conf \
    -v /my_mounted_volume/questdb/db:/questdb/db \
    -v /my_mounted_volume/questdb/log:/questdb/log \
    questdb/questdb:6.5.2 /usr/bin/env QDB_PACKAGE=docker  /app/bin/java \
    -m io.questdb/io.questdb.ServerMain \
    -d /questdb \
    -f
```

For clarity: my final goal is to be able to run the docker container in question from the same user form which I run my docker daemon (the `svc_test` user). Hence how I stumbled on this problem.

Comment: Surely it's easy to make a MVCE and post that docker file here?

Comment: What is the *specific* `docker run` command you're using? The specific paths matter.

Comment: @larsks i shared this with an update now.

Weston I don't know what MVCE is, but I hope the updated question can help.

Comment: could be wrong but don't the mounted volumes still have the same user:group and flags set on them in the container?  Maybe `ls -la` the files once inside the container.  You might need to set the user on the run command to align with the volumes.